# Blow detection on live stream audio input vs. recorded wav input

Tags: c++, svm, openal, mfcc

I am training a SVM for identifying blow in a speech signal and the trained model works almost with 95% accuracy on wav input file. I am computing MFCC features for 10ms frame with 5ms overlap.

But if I try to do make prediction on live stream, where I am reading sound card buffer with openAL and every buffer content which I fetch is 30ms long and somehow the prediction for this kind of input is not even close to 50% but on the other hand, if I record the audio input while it's being fed to the SVM for prediction and then if I check the accuracy on this recorded data, it's again 95%.

I am not able to figure it out that what is causing this difference in case of streaming audio. Any help would be great.